# What is this statue?

Tags: plot-explanation, war-machine

In [*War Machine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Machine_(film)), at a point where General McMahon has begun doubting himself, we see him solemnly walk up to and salute this statue:

[image: screenshot of a Statue from the movie]

What is this statue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Mother with her dead son” by Käthe Kollwitz.

[Photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Statue_in_the_Neue_Wache.JPG)

It's a version of the classic "Pieta" theme – Mother Mary holding the martyred Jesus.

Comment: Wow, that is some rather striking symbology. It perfectly cements the scathing commentary of the rest of the movie.

Comment: Yeah. I thought the movie was real uneven, but that imagery was striking on multiple levels; kind of tragi-comic. Tragic in recognizing the cost of individual sacrifice and comic in having the general saluting Jesus as though he was a superior officer in essence. Adds depth to his character in that both ideas are probably in his gesture. Moments like that are rare.

Comment: Idk about the comic side of that. He was definitely not an entirely serious person before that point, but after getting chewed out by the german diplomat (wow, Tilda Swinton can sell anything), he was very seriously re-evaluating his entire worldview. I felt that the salute was his way of acknowledging both to himself and the audience that he was finally disillusioned from his ideals by directly relating the suffering of the Afghan people to the victims of WW2.

Comment: Definitely. The "comic" aspect would be tiny and more ironic than anything. The moment of self-realization and re-evaluation as you say.